# React Native: how to determine list item in FlatList from a screen location

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList with multiple items of different (unpredictable) heights and after some user gesture I disable the FlatList scrolling and use a separate PanResponder to track the user's touch position as it moves over the "non-scrolling" list.

My problem is I can't figured out how to map the screen position (x, y) provided by the PanResponder to the list item that is under the user's finger. (Ideally I'd like to get both the list item index and the offset within the list item's bounding frame if possible.) I want this info so I can alter the list item's appearance as the finger moves over each item.

I've looked through the docs and searched for answers but not finding anything.

Any thoughts/recommendations on how to do this mapping?

Comment: have you checked the locationX, locationY, pageX, pageY values of PanResponder?

Comment: I can get the screen offset (pageX/Y) from the PanResponder, I just don't know how to use those values to calculate which list item is at that location on the screen.